# Modx xPDO getMany not returning expected results

Tags: php, modx-revolution, xpdo

I'm not sure what is going on here, but I'm trying to retrieve some budgets from a modx/xpdo object and getting unexpected results. From the code below, both foreach loops return the same results [that of the first getMany call. 2 items] if I switch the order of the getmany calls I get only one result for both foreach loops.

```
$tipa = $this->modx->getObject('Tipa', array('id' => $id, 'token' => $token));


// should retrieve two objects
$tipa_sub_budgets = $tipa->getMany('TipaBudget', array('budget_type_id:!=' => '999'));
foreach($tipa_sub_budgets as $sb){
    echo $sb->get('id');
}

// should retrieve one object
$tipa_primary_budgets = $tipa->getMany('TipaBudget', array('budget_type_id' => '999'));
foreach($tipa_primary_budgets as $tb){
    echo $tb->get('id');
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. What is the correct way to grab 2 sets of objects from the `$tipa` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whereas `xPDO::getObject()` can be passed the criteria either as an array or an instance of `xPDOCriteria`, `xPDOObject::getMany()` expects only an instance of `xPDOCriteria` meaning the array will not work.

Try passing an instance of `xPDOCriteria` like so...

```
$criteria = $this->modx->newQuery("TipdaBudget"); // classname, not the alias
$criteria->where(array("budget_type_id:!=" => 999));

$tipa_sub_budgets = $tipa->getMany("TipaBudget", $criteria);
```